# Odd error message when I open terminal

Tags: command-line

When I open terminal, I get the following error message:

```
 No command 'expert' found, did you mean:
 Command 'expect' from package 'expect' (main)
expert: command not found
No command 'expert' found, did you mean:
 Command 'expect' from package 'expect' (main)
expert: command not found
```

And then it displays the typical `nathan@nathan-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$`

What did I do to cause this, or at least, how do I fix this? I use terminal a lot so this has been getting annoying.

Comment: Edit your question and add the output of the following: `grep ~/.basrc ~/.profile expert`

Answer (score 3):

You probably have a typo in your ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile file - at a guess, you typed `expert` rather than `export` in a command like `export PATH=$PATH:/some/prog/path`